# excel copy/paste cell to cell using address in another cell

Tags: excel

How to Copy/Paste a value from 1 cell to 2nd Cell using a 3rd Cell which holds the address of the 2nd Cell. I want to trigger the copy/past action by a 4th Cell going 'true'. I do not want to use VB as I am not competent with it.

Comment: You can't use formulae to copy and paste. Could you give an example of what you're trying to achieve, in case there's an alternative non-VBA way to approach it?

Comment: Calculating interest payments. Wish to add additional payments against a date in the list. I have the address of the cell I want to enter the value into. The amount and date are entered from a simple 'Display' sheet, want to trigger paste with 'True' in "Display" Sheet,  all the calc stuff is hidden in a second sheet. All OK apart from pasting the amount into calculation sheet. Think I will have to learn to use VB.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use VBA I think. The only way to get a cell to show a value other than by programming is to enter a formula into your 2nd cell - but by definition you don't know what that is. Assume that A1 holds the value to copy, A3 is the cell holding the cell address and A4 is the true/false cell. Then you need this code in the module page of the sheet you wish to affect:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
 If range("a4") then 
     range(range("a3").text).value = range("a1").value
 End If
End Sub
```

Note this will error if A3 doesn't hold a valid cell address

Comment: I will have to learn how to enter VBA as it seems to be the only method. Thankyou